# Facing problem while converting a list into text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have a list that contains 700 zeroes and 700 ones. Ytrain = [0, 0, 0, 0,....,1, 1, 1,....] now I want to convert that list into a text file and the text file will be in UTF-8 encoding. I'm running my code in google colab so after downloading my output.text file it contains gibberish text like **ਰਰਰਰਰਰਰਰਰਰ਱਱਱਱਱਱਱਱਱਱਱਱**. How can I fix this?

My approach

```
with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for item in Ytrain:
        file.write(str(item) + '\n')
```

Comment: Appears to behave normally for me, can't reproduce

Comment: Are you opening the doc with a editor that is able to read the encoding?

Comment: @JoseManueldeFrutos I'm using notepad here

Comment: I also can't reproduce the issue. Make a [mre].

Comment: Can you provide the output file? It works fine for me. Also to the guy above me... this is pretty minimal

Comment: @SollyBunny here is the output file https://send.vis.ee/download/5b4bcc81d5c762b0/#PdF7lOXm_YFzUku4pJXgZw

Comment: Something really weird has happened here. The file is correct except that every character is offset by 128?

Comment: Is the google colab a windows instance, I see \r aswell as \n characters. But your code only adds \n, so it's possible the editor you are using is messing with the file and breaking it

Comment: Try reopening the file in python b4 opening it with an editor to see if it's valid then

Comment: @Solly The problem is it's not reproducible

Comment: I assume it is for him. And since "it works on mine" isn't really a solution, I would like to find out what is happening

Comment: @Solly I'm not claiming to have a solution...? I'm saying we need to be able to reproduce the issue in order to solve it, rather than guessing. Check out the link I posted. Ideally there would be one block of code that we could copy-paste, run, and see the problem. Here there could be other factors, like the input data isn't actually what OP thinks.

Comment: @Solly BTW, you need to @-tag me in order for me to get a notification. I just happened to come back here and see your reply.